# css - why is the white image unevenly distributed?

Tags: css

on this site:
http://yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=8&Itemid=34

as you can see the white background a little bit of the grey at the bottom is not solid, it stops and then starts over. do you know how smooth it out?
[alt text http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/2944/fullscreencapture131201.png](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/2944/fullscreencapture131201.png)

Comment: I can't see exactly what you are talking about... can you take a screen shot and circle what you are referring to?

Comment: Also tell us which platform, browser and browser version you're using.

Comment: i am using firefox and chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting your iframe style like bellow might work as a quick fix, but i think there is a bit of a [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) in the page structure.

```
width: 850px; height: 650px; background-color: white;
```

EDIT: for the other bits try

```
<div id="wrapper_2">
  <div id="holder">
    <div id="content" style="background-color: white;">
```

As for the footer, i think you just need to rethink how you're using the background image.

Comment: that is brilliant but still at the bottom i have a problem with the gray color, please see edited question with picture

Comment: i am unable to edit html because it is dynamically generated, i can only edit css